# array_push with associative array results in a multidimentional array

Tags: php, json, array-push

I have the following function which does some stuff and returns an array:

```
function do_work($array){ 
      $result = array();

      array_push($result, array("HAHAHAH" => "looooooool"));

      foreach($array as $key=>$val){
          array_push($result, array($key => $val));
      }

      return $result;
}
```

I originally call this and pass the `$_GET` array in it. What I expect at the end is a flat JSON object. But this returns a JSON array instead:

in my calling code:

```
$array = do_work($_GET);
 echo json_encode($array);
```

if I give the function following `GET` array:

```
handler.php?action=register_new_user&shit=happens
```

This will be the result, but I want it to be a flat JSON not an array:

```
[{"HAHAHAH":"looooooool"},{"action":"register_new_user"},{"shit":"happens"}]
```

Comment: Actually this is to be expected as you push a new value. If you want to set the key, what's wrong with a solution like [`$result['foo'] = 'bar';`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#108118)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_push` pushes the contents onto the end of the array, and you're pushing an array onto the end of an array, meaning you're creating a multi dimensional array.

If you want to merge two arrays, use `array_merge` or set the value directly if it's a single value:

```
$foo = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2);
$bar = array('three' => 3, 'four' => 4);
$foobar = array_merge($foo, $bar);

// otherwise
$foo['three'] = 3;
```